# HumanName Mother's Family

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have this:

```json
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "name": [
    {
      "family": "Family",
      "given": ["Names"],
      "extension": [
        {
          "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-mothers-family",
          "valueString": "Mothers family"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I believe that is not correct because in FHIR validator marks this error:

> "The modifier extension http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-mothers-family is not allowed to be used at this point (allowed = e:HumanName.family; this element is [Patient.name, HumanName])"

By the way I use FHIR version R4

Which is the correct form to representing Mother's family name?

Comment: Welcome! As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "name": [
    {
      "family": "Family1-Family2",
      "_family": {
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-mothers-family",
            "valueString": "Family2"
          }
        ]
      }
      "given": ["Names"],
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is that the extension must appear on HumanName.family, not HumanName directly.  (Not sure why the validator was calling it a modifier extension though, because it's definitely not.)

Comment: Looks like an old version of the validator to get that error in the error (quite old)